# appropriate preposition to use in the given sentence(s)

Tags: prepositions

People say he's a great chess player. As true as that might be, i think i can school him **at** chess.

People say he's a great chess player. As true as that might be, i think i can school him **in** chess.

People say he's a great chess player. As true as that might be, i think i can school him **in** a game of chess.

What preposition is the most appropriate to use there?
I looked up the idiom "school somebody", and in the examples the site had, they'd used **in**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either preposition will work. The two differ only subtly, and the difference does not really change the meaning. In fact, it is difficult to come up with a way to differentiate the meanings at all when used in the context of chess.